# bundleIdentifier != nil when requesting iOS10 notification authorization via UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization

Tags: ios, ios10, xcode8

I'm getting a crash saying my bundle ID is nil

> 2016-08-31 10:39:11.630 WeatherHop[52533:17767791] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: bundleIdentifier != nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:

It's failing using this code:

```
        let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier

    print("\(bundleIdentifier)")
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
        }....
```

the print statement correctly identifies my bundle ID, as set in $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Would you mind including the call stack? Or maybe even share an example project?

Comment: We just had a crash report come through for this as well... but only 1. An iPhone 6s on iOS 10.0.1 ... is there a fix/workaround or is it a fluke?

Comment: I would suggest you check any 3rd party libraries you might be using, as that was the fix for me.  Specifically, if I remember correctly, it was the "Leanplum.syncResourcesAsync(true)" call in the Leanplum SDK

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out the root cause of this error and another Core Data error mentioning photos.sqllite.  I have the LeanPlum SDK installed which I guess has some known compatibility issues with iOS10.  They acknowledged the issues and promised a new SDK coming shortly.